# how to prevent multiple program loading in windows?

Tags: windows, process

I am developing an windows application.
what I want is to prevent this application running multiple in single OS.
(e.g. we can run multiple instance of notepad.exe, calc.exe at the same time... but I don't want this)
what is the most effective way to implement this?(preventing multiple instance of process running at same time)

I'd rather not use methods like checking process names or sharing some global file as a signal... since it is too easy to circumvent

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done with mutexs. When your process launches you call [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the return value. If it succeeded then this is the first launch, otherwise there is another instance of your process alive. Your mutex should be in the `Global\` namespace. Also make sure to [ReleaseMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when your program finishes running.

Comment: Isn't this answer making assumptions about lanuguage/framework?

Comment: thank you! but my program is multi-threded and I am already using mutex as critical section management... is this going to be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using?  I'm assuming it's .Net?  Here's a post from an msdn foum on the same thing.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3e139912-45ea-432e-b9e0-e03640c07c9f/

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you don't want to check current process names or use a global file.

**Lock the current executable**

.NET example code:

```
        System.IO.File.Open(
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName,
            System.IO.FileMode.Open,
            System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
            System.IO.FileShare.None);
```

The FileShare.None keeps any other process (like Windows Explorer) from executing the file until the app closes or the file handle (returned object) is explicitly closed.

**Global Mutex**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this
>   function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object,
>   GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS, bInitialOwner is ignored,
>   and the calling thread is not granted ownership. However, if the
>   caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and the caller should use the OpenMutex function.

Global mutex is the easiest way. To clarify another answer you don't just check the return value you check the GetLastError value as well.